# looping through a character array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
bool custNum(char [], int);


int main()
{

    const int size = 8;
    char custmor[size];

    cout << "Enter a customer number in the form ";
    cout << "LLLNNNN\n";
    cout << "(LLL = letters and NNNN = numbers): ";
    cin.getline(custmor, size);
    if(custNum(custmor, size))
        cout<<"That's a valid id number"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"That's not a valid id number"<<endl;




        return 0;
}
bool custNum(char custNum[], int size)
{
    int count;

    for(count = 0; count<3; count++)
    {

        if(!isalpha(custNum[count]))
            return false;
    }
    for(count = 3; count <size - 1; count++) //3<7 , 4
    {
        if(!isdigit(custNum[count]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

so I want to loop through a character array of 3 letters and 4 numbers like ABC1234, but I didn't get the condition of the second for loop (size - 1). How does it work every time it tests the condition?

Comment: I cannot see size variable declaration anywhere

Comment: you should use "break;" intead of "return false"

Comment: I think he is asking about  why his second loop doesn't execute ?

Comment: How many elements actually in the array, and how is `size` calculated?   Note that a string literal like `"ABC1234"` is represented using `8` characters - the letters and digits, plus a trailing `char` with value zero (`'\0'`)

Comment: There is no way I can understand what you're really asking.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`), then use the debugger (`gdb`) to run your program step by step. BTW, consider using genuine C++11 constructs, e.g. `std::string custNum; for (auto c: custNum)`. BTW your question is off-topic here, since a fix-my-buggy code request.

Comment: it does execute but I just want to understand the the concept of the condition of the second loop

Comment: Also, in C++, array indexing starts at 0. Perhaps your 3 should be 2.

Comment: Also for C++ you could use `std::string` or `std::array`

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: @mohammed alharbi, Please check  my answer below :) and let me know if that didn't help  and with your exact problem :)

Comment: There is no better way to understand what's going on than by using a debugger to step through it, or print statements to show what's going on on each loop iteration.

Comment: Size-1 makes sense since you don't want test for a digit on the final \0 (only 7 real characters)

Comment: What returns true ?  is it "custNum" function returning true when size is about 12 ?

Comment: I initialized my array with 8 elements yet it accepts 12 as long as the first three are letters. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you read only amount of characters that size variable specify, 
since then , Why custNum function would not return true for anything longer than size variable ?  , Because it's not checking anything more than what size variable specify.

Below is the code you need

```
      #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
bool custNum(string,unsigned int);


int main()
{

    const unsigned int size = 8;
    //char custmor[size];

    string mystring;

    cout << "Enter a customer number in the form ";
    cout << "LLLNNNN\n";
    cout << "(LLL = letters and NNNN = numbers): ";
    cin >> mystring;

    cout << mystring <<endl << " " <<   mystring.length() << endl;
    // cin.getline(custmor, size);


     if(custNum(mystring , size))
        cout<<"That's a valid id number"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"That's not a valid id number"<<endl;




        return 0;
}
bool custNum(string s, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int count;

    if (s.length() != (size + 1))
        return false;

    for(count = 0; count<3; count++)
    {

        if(!isalpha(s[count]))
            return false;
    }
    for(count = 3; count <size - 1; count++) //3<7 , 4
    {
        cout <<  s[count] <<endl;
        if(!isdigit(s[count]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: My code works perfectly. Please explain to me the concept behind "size - 1" That's what I'm asking for. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough as English is my second language

Comment: My array size is 8 but when I input this ABC123456789, it still returns true? can you explain why?

Comment: When you initialize an array with [8] , it actually can hold 9 elements ,  

As there is an element at 0

Comment: 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5 , 6, 7,8 , 9

but if you modify your code to use [7] , it will fix your problem , then it can have only  8 elements  including element at 0

Comment: isn't ABC123456789, 12 elements?

Comment: initialize an array with [11] might help ,  yes it's 12 elements

Comment: why don't you just check for null byte  0 ?

Comment: well I initialized it with [8] yet it accepts 12, see that's what confused me

Comment: Did you get it now ? i think it explains why it return true for anything longer than size , right ?

Comment: Thank you for your time, even though I didn't really understand your answer. However, I'll rate your answer as correct and I'm sorry if I bothered you

Comment: Helloed mohammed , I have modified code , Please check and let me know

Comment: I don't know what constraint means. I'm a beginner at programming

Comment: You don't have to care about constraints, 
I have added a working code sample , Please check that and let me know

Comment: give me a moment , I haven't tested that in compiler.

Comment: Hello mohammed , I have posted a full tested code , It should work now exactly as you expect. :)

Comment: I hop you'll run and let me know how it went for you :) 

I have fully tested , And It worked fine , :) only for 9 lenght arrays it returns true , otherwise false :)

Comment: it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. Never use `count` as a loop variable.  A good name for a loop variable is `i`.
2. Never declare variables away from their initialization. The above should be `for( int i = 0; ...` in both cases.
3. `i < size - 1` is probably wrong.  What you probably want is `i < size`.

Anyhow, it would help if you showed how `size` is declared, how it is initialized, etc.  It would also help if you showed the exact text you are trying to parse.  It would also help if you explained exactly what you expected to happen, and exactly what happened instead.  I might amend my answer when you do that.

Comment: the code works. but why would I use size - 1?

Comment: Size-1 makes sense since they don't want test a digit on the final \0

Comment: @Drakes Looping while `i < size - 1` would make sense if "size" was what the OP actually meant.  But judging by the OP's mastery of naming, we could just as easily expect "size" to mean not really "size" but "length" instead.  (As in, the result of calling `strlen()`.)  In which case the loop would have needed to be while `i < size`.  That was all before the OP's amendment that showed how `size` is declared and initialized.

Comment: Yes, he added more details in comments that made my above comment obsolete now.